# log elasticsearch requests

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

How to log requests which came to elasticsearch?

I set in `elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf`:

```
wrapper.logfile=/var/log/elasticsearch/debug.log

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=DEBUG
```

But the log file shows only:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:00 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:02 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.6
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2010 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | 
WARN   | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | The value of wrapper.java.command does not appear to be a java binary.
WARN   | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | The use of scripts is not supported. Trying to continue, but some features may not work correctly..
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/11 13:00:05 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
```

No info about my requests...

I use `elasticsearch 0.17.6`

Comment: Were you able to find a satisfactory answer?

Comment: The answer from imotov was satisfactory enough for my needs.

Comment: By changing slow query thresholds ?

Comment: Yes, by changing them to 0 (I'm not sure, this was long time ago, but basically to a very low value). You might also put a proxy in front of Elasticsearch which is able to log requests.

Comment: I know about changing thresholds way. Was wondering if any new config  or logging param has been introduced since you posted this question (ES version 0.17.6 .. its 1.3.4 now) . Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no request logging facilities available in elasticsearch 0.17.6. The version 0.18.3 and above supports [logging of slow search operations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/slowlog.html), which can be configured with threshold of 0ms to log all search requests for all shards. In the version 0.19.12 this functionality was expanded to [index queries as well](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2457).

If you are interested in logging all HTTP requests, the [elasticsearch-jetty](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) plugin supports this functionality for elasticsearch 0.18.4 and above.

Comment: Elasticsearch 1.1.1 is not compatible with recent jetty implementation. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch-jetty/m-5XETJEuKo Some ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In 1.7.3

*config/elasticsearch.yml*

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 0s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 0s
index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 0s
```

and

*config/logging.yml*

```
  index.search.slowlog: DEBUG, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: DEBUG, index_indexing_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: true
  index.indexing.slowlog: true
```

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way to configure logging in Elasticsearch 5.x and above is using the API:

```
## Elasticsearch slow log
curl -X "PUT" "http://localhost:9200/test_resumes/_settings?preserve_existing=true" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "index": {
    "search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace": "0ms",
    "search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace": "0ms",
    "search.slowlog.level": "trace"
  }
}'
```

Comment: in ES 8 (maybe also in earlier versions) the setting `"search.slowlog.level"` does no longer exist. There are separate entries for `"search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn"`, `"search.slowlog.threshold.query.info"`, `"...debug"` and `"...trace"`. And also for `"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn"`, `"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info"`, , `"...debug"` and `"...trace"`.
[docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html)